# Use of android app building using phonegap

Tags: cordova

I am an android developer, I am a beginner to Phonegap. what is the use developing an android app using phonegap? Will this app run on all the platforms? Else, there is a completely different method to create a cross platform app using phonegap?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only developing for a single platform and are used to native development, the only really use would be having a webview as the mainview would allow for a web designer/frontend developer to work on the display of your app.

The design pattern for multiplatform is very hands off in regard to native. You build it like a website, outside of any native IDE and only make use of the native tools for deploy and builds. You can make use of native code by writing cordova plugins, but to a native dev this may seem more cumbersome than full on native development.